# MS Teams: remove an extension name from a ThumbnailCard

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have a message extension for MS Teams (based on Bot Framework v3). When I create a ThumbnailCard and return it to user, Teams inserts name and logo of my app to card. Can I remove them somehow?

This is how I create a card

```
var card = new ThumbnailCard { Text = "some text", Title= "title"};
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of a messaging extension that doesn't insert its name and logo into its messages? It looks like all messaging extensions do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions/messaging-extensions-overview

Comment: Yes, seems like so. I'm just interesting if there is a way to avoid that.

Comment: Adrian Solis is a Microsoft Teams developer support professional. Please accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the attribution on cards created by a messaging extension can't be removed by the app. Teams will automatically show it.

Answer (score 0):

The ThumbnailCard object has the constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the ThumbnailCard class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="title">Title of the card</param>
/// <param name="subtitle">Subtitle of the card</param>
/// <param name="text">Text for the card</param>
/// <param name="images">Array of images for the card</param>
/// <param name="buttons">Set of actions applicable to the current
/// card</param>
/// <param name="tap">This action will be activated when user taps on
/// the card itself</param>
public ThumbnailCard(string title = default(string), string subtitle = default(string), string text = default(string), IList<CardImage> images = default(IList<CardImage>), IList<CardAction> buttons = default(IList<CardAction>), CardAction tap = default(CardAction))
{
    Title = title;
    Subtitle = subtitle;
    Text = text;
    Images = images;
    Buttons = buttons;
    Tap = tap;
    CustomInit();
}
```

Have you tried with `images = new List<CardImage>()` ? same thing for buttons